# How can I fix this EOF syntax error

Tags: python

When I run my google aiy project, using `python src/assistant_library_with_local_commands`, I get:

> ***File "assistant_library_with_local_commands_demo.py", line 122
>
>       ^
>   SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
>   .***
>   How can I fix this error? I cannot find anything else on the web.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Copyright 2017 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""Run a recognizer using the Google Assistant Library.
The Google Assistant Library has direct access to the audio API, so this Python
code doesn't need to record audio. Hot word detection "OK, Google" is supported.
The Google Assistant Library can be installed with:
    env/bin/pip install google-assistant-library==0.0.2
It is available for Raspberry Pi 2/3 only; Pi Zero is not supported.
"""

    import logging
    import subprocess
    import sys

    import aiy.assistant.auth_helpers
    import aiy.audio
    import aiy.voicehat
    from google.assistant.library import Assistant
    from google.assistant.library.event import EventType

    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s"
    )

    def get_led():
        """Returns a driver to control the VoiceHat LED light with various animations.
        led = aiy.voicehat.get_led()
        # You may set any LED animation:
        led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.PULSE_QUICK)
        led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.BLINK)
        # Or turn off the light but keep the driver running:
        led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED_OFF)

    def hello_there():
        aiy.audio.say('Hello there Leland!')
       # subprocess.call('sudo shutdown now', shell=True)


    def how_are_you():
        aiy.audio.say('I am doing rather fine today!')
        #subprocess.call('sudo reboot', shell=True)

    def poo_stripe():
        #ip_address = subprocess.check_output("hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1", shell=True)
        aiy.audio.say('Today you need to make sure that you wash the five inch poo stripe out of your pants!')

    def process_event(assistant, event):
        status_ui = aiy.voicehat.get_status_ui()
        if event.type == EventType.ON_START_FINISHED:
            status_ui.status('ready')
            if sys.stdout.isatty():
                print('Say "OK, Google" then speak, or press Ctrl+C to quit...')

        elif event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED:
            status_ui.status('listening')

        elif event.type == EventType.ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED and event.args:
            print('You said:', event.args['text'])
            text = event.args['text'].lower()
            if text == 'hello':
            led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.PULSE_QUICK)
                assistant.stop_conversation()
                hello_there()
            led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED_OFF)
            elif text == 'how are you today':
                led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.PULSE_QUICK)
            assistant.stop_conversation()
                how_are_you()
            led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED_OFF)
            elif text == 'what is on my to-do list today':
            led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.PULSE_QUICK)
                assistant.stop_conversation()
                poo_stripe()
            led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED_OFF)
        elif event.type == EventType.ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE:
            status_ui.status('thinking')

        elif event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED:
            status_ui.status('ready')
        elif status_ui.status('ready') == True:
                       self._can_start_conversation = True

        elif event.type == EventType.ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR and event.args and event.args['is_fatal']:
            sys.exit(1)

    def _on_button_pressed(self):
            # Check if we can start a conversation. 'self._can_start_conversation'
            # is False when either:
            # 1. The assistant library is not yet ready; OR
            # 2. The assistant library is already in a conversation.
        led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.PULSE_QUICK)
            if self._can_start_conversation:
                self._assistant.start_conversation()
        led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED_OFF)


    def main():
        credentials = aiy.assistant.auth_helpers.get_assistant_credentials()
        with Assistant(credentials) as assistant:
            for event in assistant.start():
                process_event(assistant, event)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: missing `"""` !?

Comment: You're missing the closing quotes for the comment: `"""Returns a driver to control the VoiceHat LED light with various animations.` <--- add `"""` to the end of this line

Comment: @toxicl-16: there's a lot of indentation errors in your code. here's your code reformatted with (hopefully) correct indentations: http://dpaste.com/3A39W3X -- Try running it, and report back any errors

Comment: I renamed assistant_library_with_local_commands_demo.py to test2.py.... Sorry.

Comment: when running as a function, "src/assistant_library_with_local_commands_demo.py" I get: /home/pi/AIY-voice-kit-python/src/aiy/_drivers/_led.py:51: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway. Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings. GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT) Traceback (most recent call last): File "src/test2.py", line 119, in <module> main() File "src/test2.py", line 115, in main process_event(assistant, event) File "src/test2.py", line 95, in process_event self._can_start_conversation = True NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: When running as python file, "sudo python src/assistant_library_with_local_commands_demo.py" I get: Traceback (most recent call last): File "src/test2.py", line 28, in <module> import aiy.assistant.auth_helpers File "/home/pi/AIY-voice-kit-python/src/aiy/assistant/auth_helper‌​s.py", line 24, in <module> import google_auth_oauthlib.flow ImportError: No module named google_auth_oauthlib.flow.    The code for auth_helpers.py is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rDb3346GKsDPJjCr8Dn8TGJ3e5MrXIbz0MqoC0I3S9g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please help....

Comment: Also, I added the end quotes

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the different coloring of the source code elements, everything beyond `"""Returns a driver to control the VoiceHat LED light with various animations.` is being compiled as a comment. You need to add `"""` at the end of the line.

Comment: I make the changes then run.. returns me with: File "test2.py", line 65
    if sys.stdout.isatty():
                          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level